# Memory alignment on iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, c++, android, c, memory

As I've discovered from my tests iPhone's malloc has 16 byte alignment. But I'm not sure whether it is guaranteed or just coincidence.

So the question is: what is the guaranteed memory alignment when using malloc() on iOS and Android(NDK)?

Comment: Not sure about small amounts, but according to Apple's documentation, allocating large amounts (4KB+) is guaranteed to be page aligned.

Comment: @John Ripley can you share the link to that docs please?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html - in a highlighted box: "Note: Large memory allocations are guaranteed to be page-aligned."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

malloc in C returns a pointer to a block of memory "which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable"; whether this alignment is or will remain at 16 bytes is not guaranteed even for different versions of the same OS. Objective-C is effectively based on C, so that should hold true there too.

If your Android NDK is written in C or C++, the same should hold true there.

Comment: Hmm, I wish I knew why someone voted this down. Comments, people!

Comment: Memory alignment and minimum size returned by malloc on iOS is guaranteed and is in fact documented. I don't know if that deserves a down vote or was the cause, just a guess really.

Comment: @Steazy: But was it documented in 2011 when all this was written?

Answer (score 6):

On iOS, the alignment is currently 16 bytes, as you've discovered.   However, that isn't guaranteed, nor documented.   I.e. don't rely on it.

Assuming it is available on iOS, `posix_memalign()` allows for the allocation of specifically aligned memory.   There may be other mechanisms.

Android is not my bailiwick.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree that you still shouldn't rely on this, but for something like a hash function it's pretty helpful.

It is actually documented -
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html

Excerpt:

> **Allocating Small Memory Blocks Using Malloc**
>
> For small memory allocations, where small is anything less than a few virtual memory pages, malloc sub-allocates the requested amount of memory from a list (or “pool”) of free blocks of increasing size. Any small blocks you deallocate using the free routine are added back to the pool and reused on a “best fit” basis. The memory pool is itself is comprised of several virtual memory pages that are allocated using the vm_allocate routine and managed for you by the system.
>
> When allocating any small blocks of memory, **remember that the granularity for blocks allocated by the malloc library is 16 bytes**. Thus, the smallest block of memory you can allocate is 16 bytes and any blocks larger than that are a multiple of 16. For example, if you call malloc and ask for 4 bytes, it returns a block whose size is 16 bytes; if you request 24 bytes, it returns a block whose size is 32 bytes. Because of this granularity, you should design your data structures carefully and try to make them multiples of 16 bytes whenever possible.